# Can we integrate $\frac{-6\ln x}{x^2-2x}$?

Tags: integration

my solution:
$$\frac{-6\ln x}{x^2-2x}$$
$$=3(\frac{-6\ln x}{x^2-2x})$$
$$=3\ln x(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x-2})$$
$$=3(\frac{\ln x}{x}-\frac{\ln x}{x-2})$$

$$3\int \frac{\ln x}{x}-\frac{\ln x}{x-2}dx$$
$$=3\int\frac{\ln x}{x}dx-3\int \frac{\ln x}{x-2}dx$$

I know that $\int\frac{\ln x}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}(\ln x)^2+C$ but how to do the second part?or maybe it cannot integrate?

Comment: It consists of $Li$ function

Comment: The second term $\int\log(x)/(x-2)\,\mathrm{d}x$ doesn't have a closed form, but is expressible in terms of *polylogarithms* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

Comment: It is $$-6 \left(-\frac{1}{2}
   \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2-x}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{4}
   \log ^2(x)+\frac{1}{2} \log (2) \log (x-2)\right)+C$$

Comment: oh... I haven’t learned that. So i need to use $Li$ to solve it?

Comment: Correct, it will be expressible in terms of the Dilogarithm. I tried using integration by parts but failed. I think that a user more accustomed to these types of integrals will be able to show you how it is derived.